# DocuSign , Need to send different document to multiple recipient through single envelope

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

How to send the different document to multiple person in a single envelope in docuSign process in a parallel work-flow not sequential work-flow.

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can do this. Using the document visibility feature, you can add multiple documents and have them visible to some recipients. to read more about DocuSign Document Visibility check https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-document-visibility

(note you have to enable this feature on your DocuSign admin)